# Arabic localization in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, localization

Are there any localization modules that can help with Arabic localization for an angular app? I have looked at angular-translate, but it does not seem to support rtl languages like arabic. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next). I think it is the most commonly used localization tool, and i personally used it's node.js library for Arabic localization